# Why is the address of an object stored in shared_ptr different than the original address?

Tags: c++

I'm learning the usage of shared_ptr.

I was expecting the shared_ptr stores the original object A.

Here is the demo code https://godbolt.org/z/nqrMhcz95. I've noticed the address of a, b.a_ and sa are different.

```
struct A {

    int getValue() {
        return a;
    }
    int a;
};

struct A1 {
    int a;
};

struct B {
    B(A& a) : a_(std::make_shared<A>(a)), a1_(std::make_shared<A1>(A1())){};
    A& getA() { return *a_; }

    std::shared_ptr<A> a_;
    std::shared_ptr<A1> a1_;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b{a};
    std::shared_ptr<A> sa = std::make_shared<A>(a);
    cout << &a << '\n';
    cout << &(*b.a_) << '\n';
    cout << &(*sa) << '\n';
    b.getA().a = 4;
    cout << a.getValue() << '\n'; // expecting the modified value reflect in the original object a
}
```

Did I misunderstand the behaviour of shared_ptr?

How can I modify the value of an object stored in a shared_ptr?

Comment: ? Because it's a different object? I do not understand. You understand that your code is creating three A objects? `I was expecting the shared_ptr stores the original object A` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared constructs a _new_ object.

Comment: @KamilCuk Do you mean I have to use raw reference if I want to be able to modify the original object?

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. No, you do not "have to" use reference, you can use a pointer. Note that if you would wrap an object allocated on stack with shared_ptr, it will call delete on that object, which will most probably seg fault.

Comment: @KamilCuk How do I use the pointer to modify the underneath object?

Comment: @LunaticJape `std::shared_ptr` has operator overloads for `->` and `*`.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
A a;
std::shared_ptr<A> sa = std::make_shared<A>(a);
```

`a` and `sa` refer to different objects. `make_shared` will always create a new object, `a` is then passed to the copy constructor of the newly allocated instance of `A`.

To have two variables that both point to the same object you'll need both of them to be `shared_ptr`s:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
std::shared_ptr<A> sa = a;
```

The same applies in `B`, if you want its member to point to the same object the parameters passed to the constructor needs to be a shared pointer.

Note that if you don't want all of these objects to share ownership of `A` you could achieve the same with references but you'd then have to make sure the original object outlives all the references.

Don't be tempted to pass a pointer to an existing object into the `shared_ptr` constructor:

```
A a;
std::shared_ptr<A> sa{&a};
```

This will initially appear to work and `a` and `sa` will refer to the same object but when `sa` is destroyed it will attempt to `delete a` which is undefined behaviour as `a` wasn't allocated with `new`.

Comment: If I want to use B as a wrapper class of A, which can modify the value of the original object A, what's the best practice?

Comment: It depends, if `B` needs to take ownership of `A` use a shared pointer, if not use a reference or a bare pointer